# Does this count as asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

I was just trying to make a loop that would know whenever it's done, would this be a proper way of doing this?

**Code**

```
var map = [
  "A",
  "S",
  "Y",
  "N",
  "C"
]

for(x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
  var selected = map[x];
  var length = map.length - 1;
  console.log('Loading ' + selected);
  if(x === length){
    console.log('Loop has finished!');
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gj5xwg7/)

Comment: No, there is nothing async here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev darn, I've been trying to do something whenever the loop has reached its last entry so it's basically done.

Comment: Code after the loop would run after the loop was finished. I don't understand your issue here.

Comment: No you have a for loop the runs synchronously which means everything gets executed before the next line of code is run. To achieve something being asynchronous  time needs to be involved using something like setTimeout would excute a line of code head on to the next line and then callback some other code later on.

Comment: @Phylogenesis well it might occur that the loop gets delayed and the code gets run before the loop is done.

Comment: @MartijnKekistan No, that cannot happen.

Comment: Actually here your question in the title and in the body are not in sync.

Comment: @Enjayy so I could check if it has reached its max, if not set a timeout and do it till it hits it maximum?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it just like that (if you are not working on parallel):

```
var map = [
  "A",
  "S",
  "Y",
  "N",
  "C"
]

for(var x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
  var selected = map[x];
  console.log('Loading ' + selected);
}
console.log('Loop has finished!');
```

Comment: Yeah, but I do need it to be async. I think I'll use the the `async` package.

Comment: @MartijnKekistan If you have any asynchronous code in your real code, show us your real code. If you don't: no, you don't need anything asynchronous.